# How to remove BIOS Write-Protect Screw for HP Pavilion 14 Chromebook

Tags: bios, hp-pavilion, chromebook

I'm trying to install windows on a HP Pavilion 14 Chromebook, I followed the instruction from [How to Install Windows on a Chromebook](https://www.howtogeek.com/278953/how-to-install-windows-on-a-chromebook/), I reached the stage when I'm to remove the `BIOS Write-Protect Screw`, but I can't find it.

I have also checked a similar problem [BIOS Write-Protect Screw HP Chromebook 14](https://superuser.com/questions/837870/bios-write-protect-screw-hp-chromebook-14), but it's not the same board type.

Can anyone please help me locate where the `BIOS Write-Protect Screw` is located on this image below
[image: Front]

[image: back]

I need this so that I can continue my installation for windows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/803708/where-is-the-write-protect-switch-screw-jumper-on-the-samsung-chromebox 

I can't see your mobo close enough, to look for the jumper but look at the picture described.

Answer (score 2):

From [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/hp-pavilion-14-chromebook) the write protect screw for HP Pavilion Chromebook is actually a [switch](https://a77db9aa-a-7b23c8ea-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/hp-pavilion-14-chromebook/butterfly-top-wp.jpg). The specific model pictured is **HP Pavilion 14-c015dx ChromeBook**, and location might vary depending on model number...

[image]

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `shell` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

type `sudo -s` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

type `flashrom --wp-disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

reboot your chromebook and now you can rewrite your firmware...

Answer (score -1):

Relative to the onboard USB ports there is a silver rectangular module with the smallest black switch (the back of the mobo or opposite of the RAM/CPU) right in between the 2 usbs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you clarify with a little more specificity?