# Where is the Write Protect Screw or Jumper for the Samsung Series 5 Chromebook XE500C21?

Tags: linux, bios, chromebook, google-chrome-os, write-protect

**EDIT**

I have just realized that I've omitted one important detail, in order to get an answer to my question, which is that I installed Chromium OS (instead of the official Chrome OS). So I can't just "turn off" the developer mode, because in that case I won't be able to keep Chromium on my Chromebook. That's why I need to modify the Bios.

---

I've been trying for a couple of days to look for ways to disable the Bios Write Protect on the Samsung Series 5 Chromebook - Model XE500C21.

The reason I want to disable the Bios Write Protect, is so I can remove (reduce to 2 seconds) the Developer Mode - Chrome OS Verification Warning that appears on every boot.

I've disassembled the whole thing and have iterated over every screw on the motherboard, to see which one might be the Write Protect Screw, without luck.

I'm starting to believe that it is a Jumper instead of a screw, however there is no visible jumper anywhere.

For reference and more information, please see the pictures on this Chromium Link (I have this exact model, Also Known as Alex):

https://www.chromium.org/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook

I'm also attaching pictures of my own, so you may see the motherboard from both sides & the exact model:

Back of Motherboard: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx1Xpc2h5JHZS0xLTFhJQUVyV05rRnkzZGtFczQ4QnFaamg0

Front of Motherboard: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx1Xpc2h5JHZUW9kRjZFNF8wVWViOXZ5SFZrenVfQjNXOG9F

Chromebook Model No. : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx1Xpc2h5JHZT0dNcmdyR1d4c3ZZY012QV9uY1UxX3VaZUJJ

Please, I would appreciate any help on the matter,

Thank you very much to all in advance.

Comment: Did you check out this related post shown on the right and at the top of the Ask a Question page when you wrote the question? [Where is the write-protect switch/screw/jumper on the Samsung Chromebox?](https://superuser.com/q/803708/364367)

Comment: Yes, I did, but unfortunately it refers to a different model, so it doesn't tell me where I can find the jumper, on the motherboard that my chromebook uses. If you take a look at the pictures I posted you'll see, there is no jumper neither on the back nor the front of my motherboard.