# How do I put Chromium OS on Samsung Series 5 Chromebook?

Tags: linux, chromium, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a Samsung Series 5 Chrombook that I would like to put Linux on. According to [Chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook), it is only possible to install Chromium OS. I made a Chromium OS image using Balena Etcher on Gallium OS, but when I run `/usr/sbin/chromeos-install` as root, I receive an error message. I navigate to /usr/sbin and run `chromeos-install`, but I get the same error message. I know that it is possible to install Chromium because of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1435100/where-is-the-write-protect-screw-or-jumper-for-the-samsung-series-5-chromebook-x) question, but how?

Edit:
I just tried to boot from the image on another computer. I accidentally made an image with Chromium web browser for Linux. I went [here](https://www.neverware.com/freedownload) to get an OS iso, and I flashed it. It still will not boot on the Samsung Chromebook, it gives me a error

```
cros-disks stop/waiting
Error: Source can not be the destination device: /dev/sda
```

On another laptop, it boots up and I am able to log in.
On the Samsung Chromebook, I looked in the /media/removable folder and the drive didn't show up. It did show up when I ran `lsusb`.

I put it in normal mode, then back in developer mode because I thought that I had modified a couple of files to try to get it to boot from USB. When putting it back in developer mode, control-d does not work anymore. I tried making a recovery disk and re-installing the OS, but once in developer mode, control-d does not work. I am stuck at a white screen with the words `Chrome OS verification is turned off.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question I know, but to help others with this problem.

When on the OS verification screen close the lid of the Chromebook enough so the screen turns off *but* you can still press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> under it. Then open the lid and it should go past the verification screen. If not? Just keep repeating until it does.

Strange yes, but hey… It has worked for me.